# Induction proof verification - sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction

I want to show that, for $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$ ,  $b_{n+1}=\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}$, while $0<b_1<a_1$ we have that $a_{n+1} \ge b_{n+1}$

Base case: $0<b_1<a_1$

Let $n>1$. Suppose that $a_n \ge b_n$. We show that $a_{n+1} \ge b_{n+1}$:

$a_{n+1} - b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}-\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}=\frac{(a_n-b_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)} \ge 0 \to a_{n+1} \ge b_{n+1}$

My only problem here, is that I didn't use the Induction hypothesis.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: isn't your algebra for $a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}$ wrong though?

Comment: This is correct, I just didn't write here the whole algebra

Comment: Oops, my bad! I guess the induction comes from assuming $a_n>b_n>0$ and thus the denominator is definitively positive. In the sense that the statement you are trying to prove is that 'for all $n$, $a_n>b_n>0.$'

Comment: Cool, I figured it out, thanks !